# Magento - show different number of products on home page

Tags: magento-1.7, blocks

I want to show all the images from category 10 on the home page, which number is 24, but the limit of the site is set to 15. How can I set it to All only for the home page?

This is the block code:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" name="home.catalog.product.list" alias="products_homepage" category_id="10" template="catalog/product/list_home.phtml"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

The limit occur in the toolbar block associated to the product list block.

So you need to create a new product list class (`Vendor_Catalog_Block_Product_List` for exemple). In this class change the default toolbar block (`protected $_defaultToolbarBlock = 'catalog/product_list_toolbar';`) by your own. And then in the toolbar block change the methods related to limit (`public function getLimit() { return 'all'; }` & `protect function _getAvailableLimit() { return ['all' => $this->__('All')]; }` ).

Or you can also change the product list class and change the behavior in the method `_beforeToHtml` to not send collection through toolbar (avoid limit and order). Simpler but you lose sort order defined in toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the limit parameter like this:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" limit="24" name="home.catalog.product.list" alias="products_homepage" category_id="10" template="catalog/product/list_home.phtml"}}
```